How to solve the derivative of the expression with respect to D?
The integral is

Where the variables follow the following distribution:

Thus, the integral becomes:

Now, my code in python is to integrate the expression with \(W_{1:3}\) being \(1,2,3\) respectively, \(r_1 = 0\), \(v\), which is the variance is \(1\), and the time constant \(tau\) being \(1\), I want to estimate roots of the derivative to find \(D\) as following:
import sympy as sp

N = 3

w_n = [k for k in range(N)]
r_n = [sp.symbols(f'r_{i+1}') for i in range(N)]
D = sp.symbols("D",real=True,)
v = sp.symbols("v",real=True)
t = sp.symbols("t",real=True)

def expo_power(i=0,t=t,D=D,v=v):
    f = ((((w_n[i] - r_n[i]) ** 2)/(2 * v)) + (((r_n[i] - r_n[i-1]) ** 2)/(4 * D * t)))
    return f
def expo_power_sum(lower_bound = 2, upper_bound=N,t=t,D=D,v=v):
    f = 0
    for i in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
        f += expo_power(i,t=t,D=D,v=v)  
    return f

def P_w_n_P_r_n(i=0,v=v,D=D,t=t):  
    return (1/sp.sqrt(8 * (sp.pi ** 2) * D * t * v) ** (N - 1) ) \
        * sp.exp(-expo_power_sum(lower_bound=2,upper_bound=N,t=t,D=D,v=v)) 

def P_w_i_r_i(i = 0, v=v):
    return (1/(sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi * v))) \
        * sp.exp(-((w_n[i] - r_n[i]) ** 2/(2 * v)))

def normal_dist(x =0, m = r_n[0], v =v):
    return (1/(sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi * v))) \
        * sp.exp(-(((x - m) ** 2)/(2 * v)))

def integrand(v = v,t=t,lower = 2):
    f = sp.log(P_w_n_P_r_n(i=lower,v=v,D=D,t=t) * P_w_i_r_i(v=v) * normal_dist(x=r_n[0],v=v))
    return f

def integrate(v=v,t=t, lower_bound = -sp.oo, upper_bound= sp.oo):
    function = integrand(v=v,t=t)

    for i in range(N):  
        inte = sp.Integral(function,(r_n[i],lower_bound,upper_bound))
        inte = inte.doit()
        inte = inte.evalf()
        function = inte
    k = inte
    sp.pprint(k)

    d = sp.diff(k,D)
    sol = sp.solve(d,D)
    sp.pprint(sol)
integrate(v=1,t=1,lower_bound=0,upper_bound=10)

Now, the solution displayed is the ratio between two unevaluated integrals.
note that

and t in the python code is (tau) and we're finding the roots of the derivative with respect to (D) after marginalizing out (r_1,r_2,r_3), the integral is not being evaluated, particularly, for (r_2)
Does the integral have a closed form? if so can the derivative of the form be solved for $D$? if not, what are the alternative to produce a solution for $P'(w_{1:3}|D,v) = 0$ with respect to $D$?
EDIT: code edited after fixing bugs pointed out by @RoberDodier

instead of Asking the same Question repeatedly, please use [edit] to add information commeners request! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79300267/numerical-integration-using-smypy-doesnt-evaluate-the-expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79300673/numerical-integration-is-not-evaluated .. further, if you really have a math Question, try https://math.stackexchange.com/, which is in the same network as SO!

@ti7 well, mathstackexchange closed the question because it's apparently more relevant to programming than it is to math and editing the question I posted on stackoverflow did not unlock the question, also if you think the question is not relevant to this particular forum you could downvote it/report it as not relevant...etc you don't have to leave a comment on every question I post announcing that it's not relevant to math/programming

Can you explain what changed between your previous (deleted) questions and this one? I'm assuming there was a reason your previous question(s?) was (were) closed. Have you addressed those issues in this question?

Also, use a single tick for inline code and triple ticks for block code (or tabs, but not both, which is why all your formatted code is indented). Additionally, there is no LaTeX formatting on Stack Overflow, so keep that in mind since it can sometimes be difficult to read plain LaTeX (i.e. raw LaTeX code).

As for the math part, I'm surprised they said this is a programming question. "Does the integral have a closed form?" This is a purely mathematical question. The last part (about alternative methods) might be considered a programming question.

Must the integral be symbolic, or can your program tolerate a numeric solution?

@jared The only change from the previous question is the last part "Does the integral have a closed form? if so can the derivative of the form be solved for $D$? if not, what are the alternative to produce a solution for $P'(w_{1:3}|D,v) = 0$ with respect to $D$?" and as for the the question "does this integral have a closed form" is just a way to ask whether the code or the expression could be manipulated in a way such that the integral can be evaluated in general such that D assumes some value, but more specifically, if the integral can be evaluated using sympy over the bound [-INF,INF]

@Reinderien A numeric solution is fine I'm just not getting any solution whatsoever (unless w_n = r_n)

Does the integral have a closed form - which one? You've shown three.

@Reinderien I put one integral but, as you've noticed, we're integrating over r_1,r_2,r_3 but I'm obviously asking for the entire expression so the solution would be 1) evaluate the integral(s) (which I'm having trouble doing)  2) find the derivative of the expression with respect to D 3) solve for D. I can find a value for D if w_n=r_n but not otherwise I hope this clears any confusion, you can also look at the function integrate

I can't tell fully what's going on, but there seem to be some problems with the way the problem is stated, and I'm thinking that you need to straighten out the problem statement before seeking a solution.
If I'm not mistaken, all the distributions involved are normal distributions, and you are marginalizing (integrating) over some of them. If so, the result should again be a normal distribution (if there are still some free variables) or some constant involving the mean and variance. My guess is that if you phrased the joint distribution as a multivariate normal distribution with a suitable covariance matrix, you would be able to state the result in terms of operations on the covariance.
But even without that, it should be possible to get an exact result in terms of D, v, and t, if the problem is set up right.
The first problem I see is that the integrand (function in your function integrate) is a function of r_2 only. It should be a function of r_1 and r_3 as well, shouldn't it?
Shouldn't r_n be assigned [r_1, r_2, r_3] and not [0, r_2, r_3] ?
That function is free of r_3 suggests that expo_power_sum isn't working right.
Finally, my advice is to work with symbolic infinity (plus/minussp.oo) when stating the integrals instead of plus/minus 1000 -- substituting any finite value is likely to make the results more complicated than they need to be.

the function is a function of r_1,r_2,r_3 and that could be tested with sp.pprint(function) also, r_1 is 0 because I'm supposed to chose an initial value for the latent variable. I reformulated the code to integrate sp.log(function) and I was able to calculate a value for D but it varies greatly depending on the integration bounds and I get no result if the upper bound of integration is sp.oo

Yes, I inspected function via pprint and it is, in fact, only a function of r_2. It doesn't make sense to set r_1 equal to 0 since you are integrating over r_1. About the absence of r_3, it looks like there are two bugs in expo_power_sum: one is that range(lower_bound, upper_bound) excludes upper_bound, so you'll have to write range(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1) to ensure upper_bound is included. The other bug is that the call to expo_power should be expo_power(i, ...) instead of expo_power(i - 1, ...).

@RoberDodier thanks I fixed the bugs you mentioned however using sp.oo as upper bound still yields no results []

I tried the current version of the code (Dec. 26) and it looks like there are still problems with formulating the integrand. I think there's some confusion between 0-based indexing in Python and 1-based indexing in the original statement; my advice is to put an extra element in the w and r lists (let's say FOO so if FOO shows up you know something has gone wrong) at index 0, so that r_1, r_2, r_3 are r[1], r[2], and r[3] respectively, likewise for w. Also, log doesn't appear in the original statement, and it changes the integrand, so you can't just put it in.

You might just skip the functions to generate the integrand, and just write it out by hand. It's only a dozen or so terms, then you don't have to fix the indexing or the generating functions.
